# MariaDB foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql, mariadb, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver to send this SQL request on my MariaDB Database :

```
CREATE TABLE liaison_att_ae (
    id_attestation INT(11),
    id_ae INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_attestation, id_ae),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_attestation) REFERENCES attestation (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ae) REFERENCES ancien_employeur (id)
);
```

I'm not really sure why, but I get this error :

> Can't create table `database`.`liaison_att_ae` (errno:
> 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tables `attestation` and `ancien_employeur` both got `id` as PK.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Show us attestation and ancien_employeur table definitions.

Comment: Not reproducible https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=9bd31734368b9c5039d706fd80d2eb50